# Java Countdown Timer

Tags: java, timer

Hi I am trying to create a countdown stopwatch timer for my gym.

Here is what I have for the actual displaying and decrementing of the time: (bear in mind I used my normal stopwatch one and just edited it briefly to decrement. It is still first pass and I still want to thread it all at some stage but for now this should work. )

```
            new Timer(1,new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int seconds = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()-watchStart)/1000;
                int days = seconds / 86400;
   //these are just initialization values for testing
                            int startHour, startMin, startSec;
                            startHour = 5;
                            startMin = 5;
                            startSec = 0;
                int hours = (seconds / 3600) - (days * 24);
                int min = (seconds / 60) - (days * 1440) - (hours * 60);
                int sec = seconds % 60;
                                    String s = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", startHour - hours, startMin - min, ((startSec == 0) ? startSec = 60 : startSec) - sec );

                displayTimeLabel.setText(s);
            }
    });
```

Now my issue is:

a) It is not decrementing the minute to start with (if it starts at say 5 minutes)

b) If I start it at 30 seconds it will go into negative until it reaches a full minute then decrements the minute. ( I think I will need a method like if == 0 then minute - 1? but I fear that will break the actual count?)

Thanks.

Edit: Full program:

```
    package countdown;

    import java.awt.*;
    import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;


    public class CountDown extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;
// The component that shows the elapsed time.
private JLabel displayTimeLabel;


private long watchStart, watchEnd;


private Timer theChronometer;

// Keeps track of time when pausing the Timer.
private long pausedTime;

// Lets the program know if starting or resuming
private boolean paused = false;

// Button that changes from "Start" to "Resume" depending on pause status.
private JButton activateTimerButton;

// run the program
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CountDown count = new CountDown();
    count.setVisible(true);
    count.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}


public CountDown(){

    // initialize
    super();
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1)); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("CrossFit Slam");
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setForeground(Color.white);



    Font largeFontBOLD = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD,20);
    Font largeFontPLAIN = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN,200);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    activateTimerButton = new JButton("Start");// will display resume when the watch is paused
    JButton stopTimerButton = new JButton("Stop");
    JButton pauseTimerButton = new JButton("Pause");

    // register buttons to generate events when clicked
    activateTimerButton.addActionListener(this);
    stopTimerButton.addActionListener(this);
    pauseTimerButton.addActionListener(this);

    // the display for elapsed time
    displayTimeLabel = new JLabel("00:00:00");
    displayTimeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    buttonPanel.setForeground(Color.white);

    displayTimeLabel.setFont(largeFontPLAIN);
    displayTimeLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

    displayTimeLabel.setBackground(Color.black);

    activateTimerButton.setFont(largeFontBOLD);
    stopTimerButton.setFont(largeFontBOLD);
    pauseTimerButton.setFont(largeFontBOLD);

displayTimeLabel.setOpaque(true);


    buttonPanel.add(activateTimerButton);
    buttonPanel.add(stopTimerButton);
    buttonPanel.add(pauseTimerButton);

    add(displayTimeLabel);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


    theChronometer =
    new Timer(1,new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int seconds = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()-watchStart)/1000;
                int days = seconds / 86400;
                            int startHour, startMin, startSec;
                            startHour = 5;
                            startMin = 5;
                            startSec = 0;
                int hours = (seconds / 3600) - (days * 24);
                int min = (seconds / 60) - (days * 1440) - (hours * 60);
                int sec = seconds % 60;
                                    String s = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", startHour - hours, startMin - min, ((startSec == 0) ? startSec = 60 : startSec) - sec );

                displayTimeLabel.setText(s);
            }
    });
}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop")){theChronometer.stop();}


    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Start") || e.getActionCommand().equals("Resume")){
        if(!paused){
           watchStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
           theChronometer.start();
        }
         else{
            watchStart = System.currentTimeMillis()+pausedTime;
            pausedTime = 0;
            theChronometer.start();
            paused = false;
            activateTimerButton.setText("Start");
         }
    }


    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Pause")){
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        pausedTime -= (now - watchStart);
        theChronometer.stop();
        paused = true;
        activateTimerButton.setText("Resume");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apologies, will do so now.

Comment: Well when 1 second elapsed, you `min` is 0, so why would you expect it to be something else then 5 then? You need to do some smart rounding there. Or **use a library method**. Even the standard Java `Date` can do all this for you without errors, not to mention better ones...

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? To learn how to work with timestamps or make an easy stopwatch? In the latter case I can just post a three-line solution to the problem.

Comment: Well I would love to see that. I've never used the timer or date classes before. (May have used date but just to display the current date) Would like to see other methods too and see how I can incorporate it there. I've been googling but nothing I've found is fitting with how I want it to operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to is easily achieved using standard libraries, in particular the `Date` class.

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
long startingTime = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(5) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimestamp;
    long displayTs = startingTime - elapsed;

    String out;
    if (displayTs >= 0) {
        out = f.format(new Date(displayTs));
    } else {
        out = "-" + f.format(new Date(-displayTs));
    }
    displayTimeLabel.setText(out);
}
```

All of this is in the standard Java libraries and the Javadoc on the methods/classes should provide insight on what's happening.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and let you know if I have any issues.

Comment: Whoops, forgot about timezones, sec.

Comment: @user2792920 You're likely to have problems with the hour field, as the format will be in your timezone, not GMT (forgot it's my default, hence worked for me). I added setting the timezone as well, should be fine now.

Comment: I am trying to workout where your "startTimestamp" is coming from? do you initialize it with the current time or did you mean something else?

Comment: @user2792920 That's you watchStart. It is, as you can imagine, the timestamp when the countdown started.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. Had to tweak it somewhat - in the if statement I had to make "out" accept displayTs as opposed to elapsed.

Comment: @user2792920 You are, of course, correct. The display should take the displayTs. Would you mind accepting the answer if it resolved your question? It would at least prevent others from wasting their time answering a problem already solved.